# How to prove that exponential kernel is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The exponential kernel is defined by:

$$k(x,z) = e^{-\alpha\|x-z\|}$$
where $\alpha>0$, $x,z\in \Bbb{R}^d$, $\|x\|$ is the 2-norm.

The kernel matrix is defined by $K_{ij} = k(x_i,x_j)$, $i,j\in[1\ldots n]$.

How to prove that $K$ is a positive (semi-positive) definite matrix?

Comment: Where is the problem from? At least, we can assume $\alpha=1$.

Comment: It appears in the problem set of a machine learning course. Yes, $\alpha$ can be absorbed with change of scale of $x_i$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The radial basis function $\phi(y) = \exp(-\alpha\sqrt{y})$ is completely monotone on $[0,\infty)$. Hence, by Schoenberg's interpolation theorem (see [chapter 15](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=mukLPHQSqLUC&pg=PA101&hl=zh-TW&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) of *A Course in Approximation Theory* by Cheney and Light or sec. 2.5 of this [book chapter](http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/603_ch2.pdf), for instance), $\phi(\|\cdot\|^2)$ is strictly positive definite. Therefore $k(x,z)=\phi(\|x-z\|^2)$ is a kernel and $K$ is positive definite when the data points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are distinct (or positive semidefinite otherwise).

<strike>Alternatively, $K$ may be viewed as the [covariance matrix for two Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process#Formulas_for_moments_of_nonstationary_processes). Hence it is positive semidefinite.</strike>

Comment: Good, Thank you. Hausdorff-Bernstein-Widder Theorem and interpolation theorem are so nice and powerful!